# Exclude data from as_json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

My Model includes some country informations

```
class MyModel 
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :country, as: :country, type: Country
end

MyModel.first.country

#<Country:0x007fc6a5d5f278 @data={"continent"=>"Asia", 
        "alpha2"=>"TH",
        "alpha3"=>"THA",
        "country_code"=>"66",
        "currency"=>"THB",
        "international_prefix"=>"001",
        "ioc"=>"THA", "latitude"=>"15 00 N",
        "longitude"=>"100 00 E", "name"=>"Thailand",
        "names"=>["Thailand", "Thaïlande", "Tailandia", "タイ"],
        "translations"=>{"en"=>"Thailand",
                         "it"=>"Tailandia",
                         "de"=>"Thailand",  
                         "fr"=>"Thaïlande",
                         "es"=>"Tailandia",
                         "ja"=>"タイ",
                         "nl"=>"Thailand",  
                         "ru"=>"Таиланд"},
        "national_destination_code_lengths"=>[2],
        "national_number_lengths"=>[9, 10],
        "national_prefix"=>"0", "number"=>"764",
        "region"=>"Asia", "subregion"=>"South-Eastern Asia",
        "un_locode"=>"TH", "languages"=>["th"], "nationality"=>"Thai"}>
```

Calling `MyModel.first.to_json(only: [:name, :country])` should only return `alpha2`, `translations` and `names`

**How can I achieve that?**
I try to avoid to write an extra method for that.

EDIT:

Expected Output something like this:

MyModel.first

```
{"name": "ModelName",
 "country": {"alpha2"=> "TH", 
             "name" => "Thailand",
             "names"=> ["Thailand", "Thaïlande", "Tailandia", "タイ"]
 }
```

Comment: Did you tried `MyModel.first.to_json(only: [:alpha2, :translations, :names])` ? This should give you expected result.

Comment: it's empty. Please mention that :country is an method on myModel

Comment: What is the desired result? Please add what you want the JSON output to look like in the question itself.

Comment: added expected output example

Comment: Expected output example include names instead of translations as specified in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `as_json` method for your Model to get the desired result.

```
class MyModel
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(only: [:name]).merge(
      country: country.data.slice("alpha2", "unofficial_names", "translations")
    )
  end
end
```

Now you can get the data by calling `as_json` on Model

```
MyModel.first.as_json
```

Hope it helps !